# Question on unions of sets

Tags: combinatorics, matching-theory

Let $n >0$ and $(X_i)_{i \in [\![ 1,n+1 ]\!]}$ be non empty subsets of $[\![ 1,n ]\!]$. Show that there exists two disjoints non empty subsets $I$ and $J$ of $[\![ 1,n+1 ]\!]$ such that $$\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i = \bigcup_{j\in J}X_j $$

I found a solution using Hall theorem but I forgot it. Can someone help me ?

I don't need solution using linear algebra. I don't. If someone could provide me some solution using combinatorics...

Comment: What means $[\![ 1,n ]\!]$?

Comment: It seems that this question was already asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2177414/given-n1-subsets-of-1-2-n-we-can-find-two-families-of-subsets-with) and different answers are already provided.

Comment: @Alex Ravsky it is a notation for all the integers between $1$ and $n$. I know that this was already posted but it doesn't seem active and the solution without linear algebra isn't complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a bipartite graph with the $X_i$'s on one side and $1,\ldots,n$ on the other side. If $X_i$ contains $k$, then $X_i$ is connected with $k$. So the above theorem is now equivalent to:

For a bipartite graph $H$ with bipartitions $X$ and $Y$ such that $|X| = n+1$ and $|Y| = n$ and degree of every vertex of $X$ is greater than $0$, there exists two disjoint subsets of $X$ with the same neighbourhood set in $Y$.

Let us induct on $n$.

**Base case**: $n = 1$

For $n=1$, both the vertices in $X$ is connected to the single vertices in $Y$. So both $\{X_1\}$ and $\{X_2\}$ have the same neighbourhood. Hence proved

**Definitions:**

A vertex $v$ is said to be **saturated** by a matching $M$ if $v$ has an edge incident on it in $M$.

**Hall's theorem:**

Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with bipartition $(X,Y)$ , then $G$ contains a matching that saturates every vertex in $X$ if and only if $|N(S)| \geq |S|$ for all $S \subseteq X$ (where $N(S)$ is the neighbourhood of $S$).

**Inductive case**: Let us assume the above theorem is true for all integers less than $n$ and let us try to prove for $n$.

**Case 1**: $H$ does not have any matching that saturates every vertex in $Y$.

Since $H$ does not contain any matching that saturates $Y$, by **Hall's theorem**, there exists an $S$ such that $S$ is a subset of $Y$ and $|N(S)| < |S|$ . Now consider the graph $H'$ with bipartitions $X \setminus N(S)$ and $Y \setminus S$. Since $|X \setminus N(S)| > |Y \setminus S|$, by induction, $H'$ has two vertex sets that satisfy theorem. We can clearly see that those two vertex sets also satisfy the theorem in $H$ (Because those two vertex sets won't get any extra edges after we add back $N(S)$ and $S$). Hence proved.

**Case 2**: $H$ has a matching $M$ that saturates every vertex in $Y$.

$M$ must saturates $n$ vertices in $X$. Let the unsaturated vertex in $X$ be $u$. Consider the maximum $M$-alternating tree rooted at $u$. All the odd levels in this tree will have vertices from $Y$ and all even levels in the tree will have vertices from $X$.

All the leaves of this tree will be vertices from $X$. Let us prove this by contradiction. Let $v$ be a vertex in $Y$ that is a leaf in the $M$-alternating tree. Every vertex in $Y$ is reached by a edge not in $M$. Since $Y$ is saturated by $M$, $v$ has an edge $e \in M$. We can now take $e$ and reach another vertex $w$ and extend the maximum $M$-alternating tree by adding $e$. Hence contradiction. Hence $v$ is not a leaf. Hence proved.

Consider the sets of all vertices in $4k$ and $4k+2$ levels for $k \in \mathbb(W)$. $u$ belongs to $0$th level. Both these sets have the same neighbourhood. Let us prove this by contradiction. Let us assume they don't have the same neighbourhood in $H$. Let a vertex $w$ in one of $4k$ level vertices be connected to a vertex $v$ which is not connected with any $4k+2$ level vertex. Then $v$ is a leaf in the $M$-alternating tree. But we proved that all leaves of $M$-alternating tree are in $X$. But $v \in Y$. Hence contradiction. Similarly we can prove that for vertex $u$ in $4k+2$ level connected to a vertex $v$ not connected with a $4k$ level vertex leads to contradiction. So both vertex sets have the same neighbourhood.

Comment: Some "easy" questions : what do you mean by saturation ? What do you mean by $N(S)$ ? If it is the neighborhood of $S$, I think that the Hall theorem states $|S| \le |N(S)|$ so how do you get your result ?

Comment: A matching M saturates a vertex v if some edge of M is incident with v. N(S) is the neighbourhood of S. Hall's theorem states that "Let G be a bipartition (X,Y) , then G contains a matching that saturates every vertex in X if and only if |N(S)| >= |S| forall S that is a subset of X". I used the fact that since Y is not saturated, there exists S (subset of Y) such that |N(S)| < |S|.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something obvious...  What is $k$?  I assume by $4k, 4k+2$ levels you mean the last two $X$ levels of the tree (and the last level being the leaves)?  But if so, why is it obvious they have the same neighborhood in $H$?

Comment: By 4k levels, i meant 0th, 4th, 8th ,12th and so on levels. Similarly by 4k+2 levels i meant 2nd, 6th, 10th and so on levels. Vertex u is supposed to be at 0th level.

Comment: Let us assume they don't have the same neighbourhood in H. Let a verted u in one of 4k levels be connected to a vertex v which is not connected with any 4k+2 level vertex. Then it is a leaf in the M-alternating tree. But we proved that all leaves of M-alternating tree are in X (which contains only 4k level vertices and 4k+2 level vertices and vertices not in M-alternating tree). Hence contradiction. Similarly we can prove that for vertex u in 4k+2 level connected to a vertex v not connected with a 4k level vertex leads to contradiction. So both levels have the same neighbourhood.

Comment: Sorry for not putting them inside the answer. I will edit it so that it becomes clear.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand.  At any even level $2m$, the neighborhood of those nodes are in levels $2m-1$ and $2m+1$, right?  So a $u$ in $4k+2$ can have neighbors in level $4k+3$, which will not be connected to any nod in $4k$.  Perhaps I misunderstood the meaning of $M$-alternating tree?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, a vertex $u$ in $4k_i+2$ can have neighbour vertex $v$ in level $4k_i+3$. But $v$ has to be connected with a vertex $w$ in $4k_j$ vertex.(Note $j$ can be less than or equal to or greater than $i$). If it is not connected to any such $w$, $v$ will become a leaf in maximum M-alternating tree and that is not possible. I believe that your doubt is because you might have wrongly assumed $j$ should be greater than $i$. If it is not, feel free to comment.